# SSH connection with gitlab

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I'm having trouble cloning a repository hosted on gitlab via SSH (https works fine).
The public key has been submitted to gitlab via the web interface, but the server doesn't accept the offered key for some reason and falls back to password authenfication instead. Oddly enough ssh auth works on other servers, so I'm assuming I need to change something in ssh_config to make it work with gitlab. I would be grateful for some advice on the matter.

ssh -vT log prints the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain [172.16.64.85] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key': No such file or directory
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ja/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b6:a4:91:33:80:c3:46:82:e2:4e:21:be:7e:a0:b0:c5
debug1: Host 'domain' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ja/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ja/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ja/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ja/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ja/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@domains's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your public ssh key was properly registered in your GitLab account (as one continuous line).

The [GitLab SSH troubleshooting page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide) mentions for instance that it wouldn't work if the public key was already in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` before GitLab was setup, or if the `authorized_keys` file isout of sync.